# Construct a measurable set in $[0, 1]$ with a property

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Construct a measurable set in $[0, 1]$ such that every function on $[0, 1]$
that almost everywhere equals its indicator function is discontinuous almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct this set in this sequence:

$C_0 = [0,\frac{1}{2}]$, $f_0 = \chi_{C_0}$

$C_1 = [0,\frac{1}{4}]\cup[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}]$, $f_1 = \chi_{C_1}$

$\cdots$

$C_k = [0,\dfrac{1}{2^{k+1}}]\cup[\dfrac{2}{2^{k+1}},\dfrac{3}{2^{2^{k+1}}}]\cdots\cup[\dfrac{2m}{2^{k+1}},\dfrac{2m+1}{2^{k+1}}]\cdots\cup[\dfrac{2^{k+1}-2}{2^{k+1}},\dfrac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}}]$,$f_k=\chi_{C_k}$

we can see $m(C_k) = \frac{1}{2}$ for every $k$.

And we take $$C = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} C_k$$

then at any point $\xi\in(0,1)\cap C$, for any small neighborhood $(\xi-\epsilon,\xi+\epsilon)$,

we can always find some point $\eta\notin C$, and the set of points belongs to $(\xi-\epsilon,\xi+\epsilon)\backslash C$ is a positive measure set due to the construction.

So any function almost equal to $\chi_{C}$ will be discontinuous everywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} C_k$?

Comment: just denote $C$ as the limit construction of this kind of set. You may take binary representation of any number, and $C_k$ means the $k$th digit of binary representation is odd.